# Android SDK: source code of Contact ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm building a `ContentProvider` and I'm interesting in how Android Team builds `Contact ContentProvider`. But, when I browse `Android source code` (in `Android SDK\source` folder), I don't see something relate to my need. I just see the most relation is : `ContentProvider.java` (in folder `Android SDK\sources\android-15\android\content`), but It's just a class for custom build `Content Provider`.

Who can point out for me, which file is it, please.

thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't find that in the core sources because it's not a core package. You can find the `android.provider.contacts` classes [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_contactsprovider/tree/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts).

Comment: file name `contactprovider2.java` right ? I cannot image it so complicate than I think. My `content provider` use SQLiteDatabase but just some lines of code :)

Comment: @hqt - Yes, I believe that's the right class. It's a complicated class because the public contract it needs to support is quite complex. See the [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) class and its nested classes for an idea of what's involved. Note that `ContactsProvider2` extends `AbstractContactsProvider`, which has the core data base functionality and is considerably simpler.